# Progress Bar not showing in AsyncTask onPreExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

My current project involves downloading data from a server - this is taking around 20s so during this time I want to display a progress bar so the user knows what is going on. The downloading task is executed inside DownloadWebpageTask (AsyncTask) and I'm setting the progress bar visibility in the preExecute() but it isn't showing up. I've looked through a whole load of questions on here and I still can't get this to work. If I don't hide the progress bar in onPostExecute() I can see what is happening - even though I set progBar.setVisibility(0) in onPreExecute() the bar is not actually showing up until after doInBackground. I tried setting a TextView in onPreExecute as well to see if it's just the progress bar not working but this also failed.

Please can someone help me out here, I'm completely stuck!!

This calls my AsyncTask:

```
public void getDTCs(View view) throws URISyntaxException{       

        DtcListSingleton.getInstance().setData(null);
        status = "DTC Parsing Not Attempted";
        noDTCs = 0;

        TextView listTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DTCtitle);
        String newTitle = "Waiting for DTCs";
        listTitle.setText(newTitle);


        String stringURL = "http://192.168.1.129";
        //Check connection
        ConnectivityManager cMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInf = cMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // If connected to network carry on with DTC request
        if(netInf != null && netInf.isConnected()){

            //Download the web page as an InputStream
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringURL);
```

And this is my AsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loadingDTCs);
            progBar.setVisibility(0);
            TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DTCtitle);
            title.setText("Loading DTCs");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls){
            //params[0] is the url
            try{
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                return "Unable to retreieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            } 

            // DELETE if overcome client.print delay
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Interrupted Exception from Delaying inputstream"; 
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            AlertDialog.Builder resultURL = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActionReadDTCs.this);

            resultURL.setTitle("Result of DownloadWebPageTask")
            .setMessage(result)

            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    progBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loadingDTCs);
                    progBar.setVisibility(8);
                    return;
                }
            })

            .show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try with .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: Your min/max SDK and current version of android version ?

Comment: does it change the text ? title.setText("Loading DTCs");??

Comment: Yes I tried with View.VISIBLE, still the same problem. It didn't show the text either.

Comment: Actually I am wondering... In my AsyncTask I am calling several other tasks like downloadUlr etc - do these all need to be declared within the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Example code see if this works? if this works it means that you are making some mistake in your view showing and hiding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/download"
       android:textSize="14sp" />
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:contentDescription="@string/your_image_will_appear_here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And your java class

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** Reference to the view which should receive the image */
    private final WeakReference imageRef;public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageRef = new WeakReference(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Wait", "Downloading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            // We open the connection
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            // we convert the inputStream into bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageRef != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageRef.get();
            if (imageView != null &amp;&amp; bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Error while downloading the image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[See the result](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akN_aVLYcwM#t=19)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for replying but I have figured out my problem.

I had not posted all of my code - I was actually calling another function after the AsyncTask and once I moved all of the code following `new DownloadWebpageTask.execute(String url)` into the `onPostExecute()` my progress bar showed up just fine!